# What are Azure Bot Framework and LUIS IP Addresses [for firewall rules]?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I would like to open firewall rules for Microsoft LUIS and BotFramework.
They both use TCP port 443, *however I need the IP address ranges to unblock the business's firewall*.

*EDIT: Our Bot is written in NodeJS and hosted on-premises*

Comment: Where are you hosting your Bot framework application? On Azure or on-premise?

Comment: On premise. Thanks for the question. I should add that to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solutions architect at Microsoft has shared a link with me.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41653

There are two options:

1. You can allow the IP ranges for your region.
2. You can setup a proxy to and add IP ranges to your firewall for your proxy.

Answer (score 2):

The IP addresses can change over time, so I recommend using the `Get-AzNetworkServiceTag` PowerShell command. Details found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworkservicetag?view=azps-6.2.0

Bot Service IPs:

```
$botService = $serviceTags.Values | Where Name -eq "AzureBotService"
$botService.Properties.AddressPrefixes
```

LUIS IPs are contained within Cognitive Services Management IPs:

```
$cognitive = $serviceTags.Values | Where Name -eq "CognitiveServicesManagement"
$cognitive.Properties.AddressPrefixes
```

FYI, the link to download the JSON list of IPs has also changed: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519